# Connect kubernetes to GitLab Container Registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, k3s, gitops

I got problem with connecting my k3s cluster to GitLab Docker Registry.

On cluster I got created secret in default namespace like this

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=https://gitlab.domain.tld:5050 --docker-username=USERNAME --docker-email=EMAIL --docker-password=TOKEN
```

Then in Deployment config I got this secret included, my config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "app"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0"
  namespace: default
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
      - image: gitlab.domain.tld:5050/group/appproject:1.0
        name: app
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

But the created pod is still unable to pull this image.
There is still error message of:

```
failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden
```

Can you help me, where the error may be?
If I try connect to this GitLab registry via secrets above on local docker, it working fine, docker login is right, also a pulling of this image.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pull from a private container registry on Gitlab you must first create a `Deploy Token` similar to how the pipeline or similar "service" would access it. Go to the repository  then go to `Settings` -> `Repository` -> `Deploy Tokens`

Give the deploy token a `name`, and a `username`(it says optional but we'll be able to use this custom username with the token) and make sure it has read_registry access. That is all it needs to pull from the registry. If you later need to push then you would need write_registry. Once you click `create deploy token` it will show you the token be sure to copy it as you won't see it again.

Now just recreate your secret in your k8s cluster.

```
 kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<private gitlab registry> --docker-username=<deploy token username> --docker-password=<deploy token>
```

Make sure to apply the secret to the same namespace as your deployment that is pulling the image.

[See Docs] https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/#gitlab-deploy-token